# Counting zeros of $z^4 + z^3 + 4 z^2 + 2 z + 3$ in right half plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

On an exam the following question was given:

Determine the number of zeros of $p(z):= z^4 + z^3 + 4 z^2 + 2 z + 3$ in the right half plane $\{z : \text{Re} z > 0\}$.  I have a solution, but I want to know if there is a slicker way that could be done quickly on an exam.

Here is my solution:

**Begin Solution**

We want to apply the argument principle by integrating $\int \frac{p'(z)dz}{p(z)}$ over a large half circle in the right half plane.  We examine the image of the imaginary axis under $p(z)$.  Plugging $z = i t$ where $t \in \mathbb{R}$ we get that 
$$p(it) = (it)^4 + (it)^3 + 4(it)^2 + 2it + 3 = (t^4 - 4t^2 + 3) + i(-t^3 + 2t).$$
Note that $t^4 - 4t^2 + 3$ has zeros $t = 1, -1, \sqrt{3}, -\sqrt{3}$ and $-t^3 + 2t$ has zeros $0, -\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}$.  With this information we can see where $p(it)$ crosses through the axis's.  As $t$ increases $p(it)$ first passes through the the positive imaginary axis, then the negative real axis, then the negative imaginary axis, then the positive real axis, then the same thing again except that the second time around the curve does not pass through the positive real axis but stays below it as $t \rightarrow \infty$.  Moreover, the ratio of the imaginary part to the real part of $p(it)$ approaches zero as $|t| \rightarrow \infty$.  Thus the argument change of $p(it)$ over the interval $[-R, R]$ approaches $4 \pi$ as $R \rightarrow \infty$.  Let $I_R = \{ it : t \in [-R, R]\}$, $C_R = \{ Re^{i \theta} : \theta \in [-\pi /2, \pi /2]\}$ and $\gamma_R = I_R \cup C_R$.  Then 
$$ \int_{\gamma_R} \frac{p'(z)dz}{p(z)} = \int_{I_R} \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} + \int_{C_R} \frac{p'(z)dz}{p(z)} = (-4\pi + o(1)) + (4 \pi + o(1)) = o(1).  $$
Where we are using the fact that 
$$\int_{C_R} \frac{p'(z)dz}{p(z)} = \int_{C_R} \frac{\frac{d(z^4)}{dz}dz}{z^4} + o(1) = 4\pi + o(1)$$
which follows from the natural estimates.  Thus we can conclude from the argument principle that $p$ has no zeros in the right half plane.

**End Solution**

This solution is not quick and only worked because I could luckily find the zeros of the real and imaginary parts of $p(it) = (it)^4 + (it)^3 + 4(it)^2 + 2it + 3 = (t^4 - 4t^2 + 3) + i(-t^3 + 2t)$.  Is there something quicker?

Comment: I haven't read your solution over in detail, however you may be able to simplify it by invoking [Rouché's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouché%27s_theorem), which uses the argument principle in its proof.  You also may want to take a look at this post for inspiration https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3039324/rouches-theorem-in-the-right-half-plane?rq=1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of roots of $z^4+z^3+4z^2+2z+3=0$ in each quadrants](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2669141/number-of-roots-of-z4z34z22z3-0-in-each-quadrants) and also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459671/how-many-zeros-does-z4z34z22z3-have-in-the-first-quadrant) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930928/finding-location-of-roots-of-polynomial-using-argument-principle) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439440/show-that-a-polynomial-has-no-zeros-in-the-first-quadrant-of-the-complex-plane)

Comment: Since $p$ has real coefficients, you can compute the corresponding [Hurwitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_matrix) to show that $p$ is stable.